# Dismiss all Views from NavigationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the following setup:

> AuthVC || Navigator => TabBarContr => MainVC/SecondVC
>
> ```
>                                => SettingsVC
> ```

In my AuthVC I check if the user is logged in. If yes I just open my Navigator class which is a `NavigationViewController` and which has my "TabBarContr" as rootview. There I have two TabBarItems. In the Navigationbar of my `TabBarContr` I have a 'settings' button which opens my `SettingsVC`. In there I have a `logout` button. When pressed, I logout and want to kill everything except my `authVC`-Controller so that I can reopen my login-VC at that point.

What I am doing:
When `logout` is pressed I link back from my `SettingsVC` to my `TabBarContr`. There I call `dismissViewController`.

I thought this would work because I really get back to my `AuthVC`. But after logging in again it opens my `TabBarContr` and there I got some issues loading stuff because some objects are still living from my previous logged-in session.

**So what do I need to do to really kill everything except `AuthVC`?**

Comment: You are presenting all `UIViewController`'s?

Comment: The flow you have used sounds good to me, but I suspect a memory leak here which is keeping the objects alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"... But after logging in again it opens my TabBarContr and there I got some issues loading ..."***

If I understood you are removing every view, but your problem is your viewcontrollers are not properly restarted. You may have some retained reference so you are reusing the vc objects and then you have some issue presenting them for the second time. Try reviewing what references are not released when you dismiss/pop.

Comment: Yes correct. That is exactly my problem. Unfortunately I still don't understand why I got retained references and I thought that maybe I can force close the VC so it will not use old objects anymore.

Comment: The typical case is a retained view controller property in the top level, that should be manually set to nil when it is dismissed. If everything is set to nil (try watch object variables debugging) and the problem persists you can also have some cross reference, something like a delegate declared as retained.
You can also try to detect wich viewcontroller is not released, overriding dealloc function:
-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog( @"class %@ -> dealloc\n", NSStringFromClass(self.class));
}'

Answer (score 1):

set AuthVC as your window's rootViewController.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

instantiate AuthVC from storyboard and assign it to window's rootViewController

```
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = AuthVC
```

Comment: you mean rootviewController of my NavigationController? Or do you mean `initial ViewController`?

Comment: window's rootViewController. which is present in your app delegate. so your AuthVC will become first screen on window. then you can again continue with your normal navigation flow.

Comment: where in my AppDelegate do I set it as rootViewController?

Comment: i have updated my answer. set rootViewController to AVC on logout action.

Comment: My AppDelegate is in my Main.class. I set my AuthVC to rootviewcontroller there now. But this does not change anything. I need to do it when the logout button is pressed right? And do I even call dismissviewController anymore?

Comment: don't make any change in appledelegate or main class. appdelegate is project level class provided to every ios app. it has a window property, which acts as your application's window. all your viewcontrollers are shown on that window only.

Comment: Okay I will try this. Do I still need to call dismissViewController on logoutpress?

Comment: no need to call dismissViewController, setting up rootviewcontroller will remove all existing viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set root view controller for the window by next code in your settingsVC:

```
//Did tap logout button
self.view.window?.rootViewController = AuthVC
```

If it doesn't help you, please send how exactly you show NavigationViewController after AuthVC.

Comment: I'd still need to call dismissViewController right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let maiStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) //Storyboard in which AuthVC lies

let authVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AuthVC") as! AuthVC
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
 appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = authVC
```